# Moments of RV plus noise?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I have some observations $Y$ that I assume are come from a true value plus some measurement noise, $Y = X + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathrm{Normal}(0, \sigma^2)$. I assume that $X$ and $\epsilon$ are uncorrelated. I wish to compute the moments of $X$ from the moments of $Y$. I assume that I have some estimate of $\sigma^2$.

Therefore I am trying to expand the moments of $Y$: $E[Y]$, $E[Y^2]$, $E[Y^3],\dots$ , so that I can then write down expressions for $E[X], E[X^2], E[X^3],\dots$. I can do the first two with no problem:

$$E[Y] = E[X + \epsilon] = E[X]$$

$$E[Y^2] = E[X^2] + E[X]E[\epsilon] + 2\mathbb{Cov}(X, \epsilon) + E[\epsilon^2] = E[X^2] + E[\sigma^2]$$.

When I get to the third moment I get:

$$E[Y^3] = E[X^3] + 6\mathrm{Cov}(X^2, \epsilon) + 3\sigma^2E[X] + 6\mathrm{Cov}(X, \epsilon^2)$$

I am not sure what to do about those pesky covariance terms. My first thought was to assume that they are zero since $X$ and $\epsilon$ are uncorrelated, but apparently this is [not necessarily the case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302247/if-x-and-y-are-uncorrelated-are-x2-and-y-also-uncorrelated). If those terms can't be removed, how would I estimate them, since I don't know $X_i$ but only $Y_i$?

Also, is there a closed form expression for $E[Y^n]$?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to assume that $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent instead of merely uncorrelated? If you can make that assumption, then the covariance terms are zero.

Comment: @Bungo thank you that is a great point, I forgot that independent and uncorrelated aren't the same thing. Yes I think we can assume that $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent. That would greatly simplify things it appears